# CSS some space at the end of the page, reason floats?

Tags: html, css

I used the tag `section`, inside the section are 2 elements. The first one is a div with the class "content" and the second one is the aside. I didn't give the section a fixed hight (the section should grow with the content inside the container "content" & the aside). I floated the container "content" to the left side and the aside to the right side.

**My Problem:** 
I gave the section a margin-bottom of 25px, but nothing happens. That's why I marked the section with a bgcolor (bgcolor = red). But the section is only as high as the aside.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
}
.navbar_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 800px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar_li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
a {
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
a:hover {
  color: #CCC;
}
section {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 1012px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
.content {
  width: 750px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(30, 30, 30);
  background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
  float: left;
}
aside {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}
p {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 730px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.asd {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #191919 0px, #373737 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>XXX</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="title.png" type="image/png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navbar_ul">
      <li class="navbar_li"><a href="http://www.google.de">Seite erstellen</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar_li"><a href="http://www.google.de">Seite löschen</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar_li"><a href="http://www.google.de">Seite bearbeiten</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Überschrift des Artikels</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <div class="header">Schritt 1 "erstellen"</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatpsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
        nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <div class="header">Schritt 2 "bearbeiten"</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <div class="header">Schritt 3 "löschen"</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsu. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatm dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
        et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

      <div class="header">Schritt 4 "mit Bild"</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsu. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatm dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
        et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <aside>
      <a class="asd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsu. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatm dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</a>
    </aside>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you remove the height on the `section`, then to fix the floating issue you must set an element before the ending tag of `section` that will not allow floating elements on both side.

So to do that I added an element before the ending tag of `section` `<div class="clearBoth"></div>` which has a style `.clearBoth: { clear:both}`

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
}


.navbar_ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 800px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar_li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

a{
    color: #666;
    display: block;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover{
    color: #CCC;
}

section{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 1012px;
    background-color: red;
}

.content{
    width: 750px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(30, 30, 30);
    background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
    float: left;
}

aside{
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
}

p{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 730px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.asd{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify; 
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #191919 0px, #373737 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

.clearBoth {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>XXX</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="title.png" type="image/png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="navbar_ul">
                <li class="navbar_li"><a href="http://www.google.de">Seite erstellen</a></li>
                <li class="navbar_li"><a href="http://www.google.de">Seite löschen</a></li>
                <li class="navbar_li"><a href="http://www.google.de">Seite bearbeiten</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <section>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="header">Überschrift des Artikels</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <div class="header">Schritt 1 "erstellen"</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatpsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <div class="header">Schritt 2 "bearbeiten"</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <div class="header">Schritt 3 "löschen"</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsu. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatm dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                <div class="header">Schritt 4 "mit Bild"</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsu. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatm dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
            
            <aside>
            <a class="asd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsu. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatm dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</a>
            </aside>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already tried it with clearfix, but i used it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: No prob. Glad to help!